# Android studio Multi Fragments in 1 activity implementation

Tags: android-studio, android-fragments

Hi I am hoping someone can clear some confusion I have from reading this site (Section 4.2) http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFragments/article.html
and some code I seen via Youtube  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oN2AAhaOBf8

My Question: One Activity and two fragments..but you only want to see one fragment at a time.  within the activity_main xml file  instead of having

```
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/message_fragment"
        android:name="com.example.android.fragments.MessageListViewFragment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="top" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/send_fragment"
        android:name="com.example.android.fragments.SendMessageFragment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="bottom" />
```

Should I replace each fragment with FrameLayout? or Would i just have one FrameLayout...I have seen both, not sure which one is correct.  Thank you, Im just trying to understand..From research I am assuming FrameLayout allows only one fragment to appear at a time??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> FrameLayout is designed to block out an area on the screen to display a single item. Generally, FrameLayout should be used to hold a single child view... You can, however, add multiple children to a FrameLayout and control their position within the FrameLayout by assigning gravity to each child.

You can use `android:visibility` tag and toggle between `visible/invisible` on need basis. This would work irrespective of any layout.

Comment: okay so under one fragment1 make it visible and the fragment2 invisible, so what does it mean child view?

Comment: are you saying by changing fragment to FrameLayout will not make a difference as in seeing one fragment at a time?

Comment: yes, by following the above, only one view is being visible at a time that is occupying entire parent.